# Number of ways to get a flush from shuffled cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

How many different ways are there to draw a flush from a well shuffled full deck of cards?

If correctly counting, I suppose the answer is $\frac{13\times 12\times 11 \times 10 \times 9}{1\times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5}$, but would like to know your thoughts on it.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability

Comment: But what exactly is the number of ways to choose any flush from shuffled cards?

Comment: Add the totals of royal flush, straight flush and non-royal/straight flush in the link (since all three cases are disjoint).

Comment: See the columns "Frequency" and "Mathematical expression of absolute frequency".

Comment: Should we sum straight flush, or not? Since cards are not the same suit?

Comment: "A straight flush is a hand that contains five cards of sequential rank, **all of the same suit.**" From the same link

Comment: Yeah I also agree on that definition. I just saw the picture and guessed it is sth. wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select $5$ cards from a suit in $\binom{13}5$ ways, and since there are $4$ suits, multiply it by $4$, which you did not.

Comment: So, the answer is $\binom{13}{5} x 4$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the same value you would end up getting if you were to add the totals of royal, straight and non-royal/straight flush in the link in the comments.

Comment: But according to previous post, we have to sum up all straight, royal, and non-royal/straight flushes to get the answer, which seems to be higher than you proposed one.

Comment: @AnarRzayev Are you sure you are adding the values correctly? $\binom41+\left[\binom{10}1\binom41-\binom41\right]+\left[\binom{13}5\binom41-\binom{10}1\binom41\right]=\binom{13}5\binom41$

Comment: Oh I see, I added up "straight" cards as well. Yes, it is absolutely correct! Thank you